# Side menu hide issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table view as a side menu on a ViewController xib that has to be added as a subview by clicking on a particular menu button.A logout button exists on side menu bottom.I want to perform `popToRootViewController` on click of logos button.

I am adding menu like this :

```
menuViewController?.view.frame = self.transparentView.frame
menuViewController?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
menuViewController?.view.frame.size.width = (mapView.frame.size.width)/1.5
menuViewController?.view.tag=10
self.transparentView.addSubview((menuViewController?.view)!)
```

Comment: Please provide some code, and tell clearly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please provide your code blocks where you faced issue ?  Try to use :  REFrostedViewController for slide menu, Its easy to use and capitalized

Comment: see i have updated my question

Comment: how you are adding menuViewController in stack?

Comment: No just add as a subview.

Comment: Give more details about your rootViewController and how you are adding menuViewController?

Comment: I have a view controller that has a menu button,On click of menu button I am able to open side menu through above code with a transparent view.Now on side menu i have a logout button that is below from table view not in tableview so i want to perform pop functionality on that logout button.

Comment: To pop to rootViewController we have to know your view controllers hierarchy, so give more details that how are you setting rootViewController in app delegate and how are you adding menuViewController?
Are you using any library?

Answer (score 1):

if you have single Navigation Controller chain in your application you can easily use below code to navigate on RootViewController.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

if let navigationController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
   navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: I appreciate your comment but I need something else.My scenario is like that - I have a side menu written in objective c class with xib  that I am displaying via presenting method not push then I want to perform logout method that can navigate me on root controller .I am logging via facebook if user already logged in then app delegate directly navigate to landing page not that fb logging page.One more thing all my code in storyboard with swift except side menu that is in objective c.

Comment: Ok so you need same code in Objective C or above code is not working at your end ?

Answer (score 1):

Use NotificationObserver to achieve this goal.

**Objective-C**

In your mainViewController's `viewDidLoad` method write below code.

```
[[NSNotificationCentre defaulCentre] addObserver:self withName:"LoggoutNotificationMessage" selector:@selector(shouldLogout:) withObject:nil];
```

now add this method in this class

```
-(void) shouldLogout {
    //Code to Pop to Root VC
}
```

Now in your ViewController class where you have implemented side menu's tableView delegate and datasource.

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method write below line.

```
[[NSNotificationCentre defaultCentre] postNotification:"LoggoutNotificationMessage" withObject:nil]
```

**Swift 3.0**
// in main ViewController.swift's `viewDidLoadMethod`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(shoudLogout), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "LogoutNotificationMessage"), object: nil)


@objc func shoudLogout() {
    //Pop to root vc here
}
```

Now in your ViewController class where you have implemented side menu's tableView delegate and datasource.

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method write below line.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "LogoutNotificationMessage"), object: nil)
```